# Написание логических выражений с отрицанием, объединением и пересечением

Tags: haskell

Извините если вопрос слишком банальный, в haskell не сильно разбираюсь, есть следующее логическое выражение 
`not A \ ((B объедение С) \ (B пересечение С))`  `где \ - вычитание`.
 Есть файл hs с функцией, которая вычисляет результат из трех множеств значений например `[1,2,3,5,8,9] [2,5,4,6,7] [1,6,4,8,78]= 2,3`

С помощью подключения Data.Set я смог использовать функции union и intersect, а как в haskell записать отрицание A в данном выражении ? 
Сама функция у меня выглядит следующим образом :
`getD a b c = (not a \\ union b c) \\ intersect b c` , но терминал ругается на булевый тип. Универсальное множество - от 1 до 10

Компилятор GHC

Comment: `not А` означает дополнение множества. Дополнение до чего? Видимо, до множества всех целых чисел? Но тогда это дополнение бесконечно - это нельзя задать перечислением конечного числа элементов. Вы уверены что вам нужен именно такой результат - бесконечное множество в ответе? Если нет, в формулировке задачи чего-то не хватает. Например определения универсального множества задачи.

Comment: Универсальное множество есть - от 1 до 10

Comment: Тогда `not A` означает `<универсальное множество> \ A`. И вся недолга.

Comment: ((<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10> \\ a) \\ union b c) \\ intersect b c ?

Comment: только перед a не \\ а \

Comment: как скобки расставить, чтобы терминал не ругался ?

Comment: сделал следующим образом : (<1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10> \ a) \\ (( union b c) \\ (intersect b c)) , пишет parse error on input ')' и указывает на скобку, которая после 'a'

Comment: `fromList [1..10] \\ a \\ (union b c \\ intersection b c)` только результат будет `4,6,10`, не знаю откуда тут должно получиться `2,3`

Comment: 2,3 я написал для примера, это неправильный ответ